# PHP Searching and Matching Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays;

> $customers_in_db contains all customers in the DB (35,000 rows)
>
> $new_customer_details contains details of 1 customer which is being
> imported into the DB

I need to be able to match the importing customer by mobile and forename.
If these do not match 100%, it is not the same customer.

Around 800-1000 customers get imported at a time, so looping through each customer in the $customers_in_db for each new customer is not viable... the server times out.

$new_customer_details array

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [forename] => Max
                    [mobile] => 123456789
                )
        
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [forename] => Smith
                    [mobile] => 456789123
                )
        )
```

$customers_in_db Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 754
            [forename] => Tom
            [mobile] => 5786413257
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [forename] => Max
            [mobile] => 123456789
        )
)
```

In the case above:
$new_customer_details[0] should match with $customers_in_db[1]

In my head its a really simple search, but as it is a multidimensional array, I'm not sure how to match values within nested arrays.

EDIT
Process:
MySQL to get ALL customers
Put each one into a multidimensional array

fgetcsv()
loop through each row in csv file
within each loop create an array with the customers details
use this new array to match to existing customers array
If there is a match, merge customer details. If no match, create new customer record

```
while($data = fgetcsv($f)){

      //Create array with details (Used later in script, so not only for matching to existing customers array)

      $customer_data = array(
        'forename' => $data[0],  
        'surname' => $data[1],
        'mobile' => $data[4]
      );

//This is what I have been trying, but not the right solution:
if(($customer_data['mobile'] != '') && ($key = array_keys($current_customers, $details_to_search)) !== false){
               return 'Match'
            }
```

I can't assume that the mobile is present for every new customer, so making the array key a certain value may not be the right way to do it?

Comment: Not sure what your query looks like, but you may want to take a look at using some sorting/indexing.

Comment: Can you expand on that? Im doing simple tests now so my query is a simple SELECT x from customers. I am then putting them into an array purely to store them without having to do more queries. Each time a new customer loop occurs, it should look into that array and check if there are any matching customers. If there are then it will merge them, else create a new record.

Comment: if `new_customers_details` matches with `customers_in_db` what you want to do ? I mean keep the matches in an array ?

Comment: It will be easier when you share your actual code.

Comment: Please share your DB schema

Comment: I have updated the question with some more detail

Comment: It would be far easier to query the DB for each customer you want to test. Since you have not shared your DB schema, it's going to be impossible for us to help you with that. If you want to do it by caching the entire DB in an array (not recommended), I suggest you simply make keys consisting of `<forename>-<mobile>` (values are irrelevant), and using `array_key_exists()` to test if a given customer exists, e.g. `if (array_key_exists( "$forename-$mobile", $customers_in_db )) {...}`, where `$forename` and `$phone` are the name and phone number of the new customer you want to test.

Comment: Ok so querying the database should be better performance-wise than storing it all in an array and trying the search that way? The only reason I went with the array option, was because I thought that caching would take less of a performance hit.